# how to obtain the information from input field inside php

Tags: php

I have a form in which I have the following field : `<input class="form-field"  type="file" name="photo" />`

how I can get the information from this field to be used in a if cycle in php ? `if ($photo != '') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [$_FILES superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Incidentally, file uploads won't work unless

1. the form method is POST,
2. the form type is `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Two seconds spent searching the phrase "PHP file upload" would probably answer this question, but it you *want* to waste that time here, \*shrug\*. People spend a lot of time complaining about PHP, but it does have fairly decent and easily searched documentation.

Comment: What I just need is only to know if the file upload filed there is a file or not.

Comment: Well, @VladimirVasilev, that information too is in the $_FILES superglobal.

Comment: I am trying with $check = $_FILES[photo];
if ($check != '') but it is not working either

Comment: Throw in a `var_dump($_FILES)`, have a look at the output, read the documentation, and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this info into the [$_FILES superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Example:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

// your ($photo != '') is here
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    ...
}
```

Source: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score 0):

[POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) 
You can check this examples of how to works $_FILES, sorry for my bad english